# Multiple instances of model components in Java Swing?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, swing, jtable, tablemodel

Until now I had different model classes for the appropriate Java Swing component, for instance I have several `TableModel` for several `JTable`. Every `JTable` has its own `TableModel`. The `TableModel` is based on one object (`Model`), giving all the required data. Something like this:

```
public class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

Model model;
```

But now I would like to make a change. My interface offers the possibility of multiple instances of `Model`. So my question is, what should I do?

- instantiate multiple objects from `MyTable`
- change dynamically the current reference to the model upon user interaction

So the basic problem I am facing: I want to use the same `JTable` with the same `TableModel`. Should I use multiple `TableModel` or should I use changing references to the data source?

---

Similar question:

I want to offer multiple tabs, they change the instance of the underlying model. The do not change the type, but the current instance - meaning, the data changes.

Should I now:

- instantiate multiple objects of the view components? For instance instantiate for every available model an own `JTable`, `JPanel`, `JScrollPane` object?
- change dynamically by listening to change events on the tabbed pane the reference of the underyling model

Comment: for me always, every JTable has its own TableModel, reason each JTable could has different TableModel (Defalut/Abstract), different ColumnModel, RowModel, RowFilter, RowSorter, MVC rules and end with definitions in prepareRenderer, anyway good question +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to have multiple tabs with a different tab having a different model then the answer is easy, you need different tables.  At least one for each tab.

Again, if you multiple tabs then you will also need multiple JScrollPanes, etc.

However, if you are going to have a single spot for a table, you might be able to get away with a single JTable and multiple models if you aren't doing something custom to the table.  (See mKorbel's comment).   Either way you could reuse the same JScrollPane.

Answer (score 2):

If the structure of the table stays the same (i.e. same number of columns, same titles, same column classes), and only its content changes, you should keep the same model instance but change the data (and call `fireTableDataChanged`). 
This will be more efficient, and will allow keeping the current column order, the current sorted column, etc.

If the structure of the table completely changes, changing the model itself is probably easier. You could also call `fireTableStructureChanged`, but the javadoc of this method says :

> This is the same as calling
>   setModel(TableModel) on the JTable

Regarding the tabs, the same rule can be followed.